# Regex match 1024x768 but not 1024x768x16

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to match `1024x768` but not `1024x768x16`. Here is the pattern. This is the code I'm using:

```
if @config[:resolution] !~ /[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}/
  raise "Invalid resolution format: #{@config[:resolution]}"
end
```

I know I'm missing something around greediness but can't find a solution

Comment: Are these individual strings? Then use anchors `\A[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}\z`.

Comment: I feel like this is an XY-problem. Is the string user input? If it is not and only a few possibilities are allowed, then you should probably use `case` statement with a list of exact strings as conditions rather than using a regex. Or, if you know that the string is not wild, then you can just count the number of `x` in the string; that would be enough.

Comment: I'm perplexed. Why isn't this just `@config[:resolution] != "1024x768"`?

Comment: Because I want to support any resolution as long as its in the format widthxheight

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. Incidentally, I did not see your reply until now because I was not notified that you posted it. You should have included `@Cary` in your comment. I'll delete both this comment and my earlier one when you've seen this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the entire string, you can add [`^` `$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) anchors to point to the start and end:

```
/^[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}$/
```

If that is not the case, you can use a [negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?<![0-9]x)[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}(?!x[0-9])/
```

Also, use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: /^\d{1,4}x\d{1,4}$/ Is exactly what I needed. It works.

Answer (score 0):

If you succeed in matching `1024x768` with a regex, then put `\A` in the front and `\z` in the end of that regex.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use word boundaries, if this string is part of a larger string

```
/\b[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4}\b/
```

Some commenters seem to think that the word boundary token will not prevent the match.

A word boundary is defined as being between a word and a non-word character.  In Ruby, word characters include Unicode letters, Unicode digits and the underscore, so this should work.

See the [example](http://rubular.com/r/pG76rR14KQ) at rubular.com

Comment: Position between a digit and `x` is a word boundary.

Comment: @sawa Is Ruby different from all the other Regex flavors?

Comment: @stribizhev  It works in my emulator.  Let me do some research.

Comment: @stribizhev  I have posted a link to a Ruby regular expression editor showing that, indeed, `\b` prevents the match.  See my edited answer